# What type of Arduino is this?

Tags: board

I found a bunch of Arduinos (seemingly), but I can't identify the type.

I first thought of a **Micro**, but the chip is a MEGA328PAU and the Micro should have a MEGA32U4 instead:

[image: Chip of the unknown Arduino]

I know it's also not a **Nano**, because the Nano is a bit longer:

[image: Comparison of unknown Arduino with Nano]

Next, I looked up the [List of Board Specs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Products/Compare). Based on the chip, the following models remain:

- Lilypad, can easily be excluded due to its shape
- Lilypad SimpleSnap, can easily be excluded due to its shape
- Uno, can easily be excluded due to its size
- Ethernet, can easily be excluded, because of the Ethernet port
- Mini
- Pro
- Pro Mini

So I am left with **Mini**, **Pro Mini** and **Pro**. The back of the board is not very helpful, since it IMHO misses the markers in the silk sceen:

[image: Back of the board]

It definitely looks like the [**Pro Mini** from Arduino Store](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-pro-mini), but the Arduino store seems not to offer the Mini and Pro, so I don't have a comparison.

What type of Arduino is this? And, if possible, do you have a visual comparison of the three remaining types?

Comment: The voltage regulator is BAPG (sure) and the quartz has A.8 on it (very hard to see)

Comment: the only info about the marking I found, has 8 for 8 MHz and X for 10 MHz. I would guess A is 16 MHz. my 16 MHz Nano has A as first letter on the resonator too https://www.murata.com/en-us/support/faqs/products/timingdevice/ceralock/char/cch0005

Comment: did my answer help?

Comment: @Juraj: sort of. It strengthens my opinion that it is a Pro Mini, but it does not eliminate the other two options: Mini and Pro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a version of Pro Mini.
[here in DIY MORE shop](https://www.diymore.cc/products/pro-mini-atmega328-3-3v-5v-16m-replace-atmega128-for-arduino-nano?_pos=6&_sid=8931d4b6d&_ss=r)

The Mini has regulator. Power it over RAW pin with 7 to 12 V and measure the Vcc pin if it shows 5v or 3.3 V.

To determine the frequency, look at the resonator (the component next to pin 2).

EDIT: the resonator markings are hard to read and very cryptic. to determine the frequency you could install Sparkfun boards package. There you can select the different variants of Pro Mini. Upload Blink. If the upload is successful and it Blinks in 1 second intervals, you have the right setting.

Comment: Unfortunately, the marks on the back are missing. If it's really a 8 MHz version, it might allow Vcc = 3.3V only.

Comment: @DataFiddler The only difference between the 8Mhz and 16Mhz version is the crystal and the regulator. You can run a 8Mhz 3.3V Pro Mini fine on 5V. Though not the other way around, since the ATMega328 requires at least 3.8V to run at 16Mhz (higher speeds, require a higher supply voltage).

Comment: Do you think the Mini and Mini 05 are just one thing? If so, this would be the Mini: https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mini-05

Comment: there are different revisions of Mini, but the Pro is different. Pro has A6 and A7

Comment: here is yours https://www.diymore.cc/products/pro-mini-atmega328-3-3v-5v-16m-replace-atmega128-for-arduino-nano?_pos=6&_sid=8931d4b6d&_ss=r

Comment: @ThomasWeller, and the voltage and frequency?